# Weird JPG file error

Tags: files, ascii

I have a `.jpg` file and I am not able to open it. If I am trying to open the file then I get the following:

```
Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2d 0x6e)
```

Also, the file command it's giving me some ASCII text, with very long lines.

The strings command applied on the file is showing me a lot of hex code. Below it, is a part of the strings command output.

```
-ne \x05\x74\xac\xda\x87\x99\xc1\xfe\xae\xe2\xfb\x7e\x27\x9c\x53\x8f\x4a\xf4\x74\xf8\x57\x6c\x18\x16\xbe\x99\x87\xa6\xd1\x5a\xb6\x5e\x00\xd1\xec\xce\xe3\x6e\x66\x23\x90\x64\x39\xa9\x96\x6f\x46\x3f\x0e\xa6\x94\xb8\x73\x15\x2d\x25\x64\x79\x7e\x9d\xa4\x5f\x6a\x92\x6c\xb4\xb6\x79\x4e\x71\x90\x3e\x51\xf8\xd7\x73\xa0\x7c\x3a\x48\x08\x9f\x53\x61\x2b\x0e\x44\x4b\xf7\x47\xd7\xd6\xbb\x5b\x5b\x38\xed\x53\x64\x51\x2c\x6b\xd8\x28\x02\xa7\x03\xda\xbc\xbc\x46\x67\x52\xae\x8b\x44\x7d\x06\x0b\x87\xe8\x50\xb4\xa7\xef\x3f\x32\x2b\x6b\x75\xb7\x40\x88\xaa\xaa\x06\x00\x03\xb5\x4c\x28\xef\x4a\x2b\xcd\x7b\xdd\x9e\xf4\x62\xa2\xac\xb6\x0a\x28\xa2\x82\x82\x8a\x28\xa0\x02\x8a\x28\xa0\x02\x83\x45\x06\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x28\xa2\x80\x0a\x4a\x5a\x28\x00\xa2\x8a\x28\x00\xa2
```

Is there any chance to convert that file to an image? Or are there any tools to investigate the hex code within the image?

That's part of CTF, so there might be a chance to find something in that file.

If you have any tools, ideas or suggestions I would appreciate your help. Many thanks!

Comment: Did you try to completely remove the file ending and open it with, for example, gimp, or check the output, as mentioned, with `file yourfilename` from terminal?

Comment: Yes, It's opening as a text file if I remove the file ending. The file command it's still gicing me ASCII text, with very long lines.